# Realistic projectile motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, rotational-dynamics, projectile, drag

I am working on a project involving a simulation of the motion of a projectile (in 3D) aimed at a moving target. The way projectile motion is analyzed in most introductory physics books is not accurate enough for this project. I would like to know what other influences on the motion of a projectile, including air resistance and spin, I need to take into account. What is a good book on this subject?

Comment: As a book recommendation I think this is already covered by the linked question, which lists suggested books on Newtonian physics.

Comment: @David: this is about video game physics, the motion of general rigid bodies with friction, and it isn't covered in classical mechanics books.

Comment: I figured that instead of saying the question needed to be edited, I might as well go ahead and edit it. I did make a pretty significant change, so Creative, please look over this and see if it matches what you wanted to ask. If not, go ahead and change it so that it does.

Answer (score 2):

If you have time to read a book, I strongly recommend Richard Feynman Lecture on Physics:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Feynman_Lectures_on_Physics

It is everything you want from a book:

- fun to read
- never boring
- it will change the way you see the world
- everyone can read it

In your case, I would focus on the first volume, Mechanics I, particularly from chapter 8.

Comment: Feynman doesn't cover general rigid bodies, beyong remarking that you need a tensor of inertia.

Comment: @Ron, Ok got it. But the other textbooks I have about this are in french. I also have the "Classical mechanics" from Goldstein, but it might be not very introductory...